# Switch user on Google Compute Engine Startup Script

Tags: google-compute-engine

I pass the following as my GCE startup script but it always logs in as the root user and never as the demo-user. How do I fix it?

```
    let startupScript = `#!/bin/bash
    su demo-user
    WHO_AM_I=$(whoami)
    echo WHO_AM_I: $WHO_AM_I &>> debug.txt
    cd..`
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work like that:

```
#! /bin/bash
sudo -u demo-user bash -c 'WHO_AM_I=$(whoami);
echo WHO_AM_I; $WHO_AM_I &>> debug.txt;'
```

use "`sudo-u`" to specify the user, then `bash -c` 'with all the commands between these particular quotes `''`  and separated by `;`

For example: `bash -c 'command1; command2;'`

You can try an easier test **(it worked for me)**, for example:

```
#! /bin/bash
sudo -u demo-user bash -c 'touch test.txt'
```

And then check with `ls -l /home/demo-test/text.txt` that demo-test is the owner of the new file.